# VxWorks memory management (beyond comprehension)

Tags: memory-management, vxworks

I have a question about VxWorks memory management.
Our program (using c++) use big struct that size is 470MB over. (I recognized this is special case.)
I added a parameter at the bottom of the struct. and input value by function.
I displayed this parameter by using "printf".
This is correct. But I displayed parameter's address  with memory dump, there is no parameter.
What is this reason?

```
struct {
    double d[...][...];// big size over 470MB
    int i; // add parameter;       
} S_tmp;
S_tmp Stmp;
void function(int i) {
    S_tmp.i = i;
    printf("i=%d,address=%p\n",S_tmp.i,&S_tmp.i);
}
int main () {
    function(2);
}
```

---

(shell output)

> i=2,address=0x12345678
>
> d 0x12345678

0x12345678 00000000 00000000 00000000 ...

---

"I cannnot find written value(2)"

Comment: Which version of VxWorks are you using? Starting from 6.x there is no longer single memory space, each process should have separate virtual memory. So I can think of `main()` running in one process and vxwhell in another, so address printed by `main()` has no meaning outside it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I understand it.